# Nancy: HttpBasic Authentication - After a successful registration can the user can be logged in immediately?

Tags: c#, .net, basic-authentication, nancy

I would like new users to be automatically authenticated after they have successfully registered.

**Current Flow**

1. User registers supplying username and password
2. User is redirected to protected content
3. User is challenged and has to re-enter their registration credentials.

**Desired Flow**

1. User registers supplying username and password
2. User is successfully redirected to protected content

I am using *HttpBasic Authentication* (plus SSL) on a NancyFX, C# .NET stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need seems like a form of **Forms Authentication**.

You do **not** have to use ASP.NET forms authentication but can simulate that using a cookie. So instead of browser challenge, you show a form and on successful entry, you set a cookie.

---

Alternatively after browser challenge, set the cookie on server and check for that on subsequent calls.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rely on cookies. Instead I am wondering if it is possible to set Authentication headers in server-side code and redirect to protected content?

Comment: @biofractal no, you cannot. All you can do is set cookie to be returned. And you can trust it, everyone does. All new security standards such as OpenId and ADFS work on cookies.

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice. I will give your suggestion a go. I don't suppose you have a bare-bones example in c# you can point me to?

Comment: @biofractal I am afraid not. But if you start and hit troubles, ask a question and leave me a note.